# styling a css menu with section dividers and onHover styles

Tags: html-lists, css

Hi i am making a menu,

its built up with UL and LIs

please can you advise me on how i can do the lines after each li and do the indent with that particular bullet image.

Here is the menu i am using if you want to see code: http://www.dnn-menu.com/superfish/Home.aspx

here is an image of the design:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi u can make this navi in pure css

example is

**HTML**

```
<ul class="navi">
<li><a href="">Lorem text here</a></li>
<li><a href="">Lorem text here</a></li>
<li><a href="">Lorem text here</a></li>
<li><a href="">Lorem text here</a></li>
<li><a href="">Lorem text here</a></li>
<li><a href="">Lorem text here</a></li>
</ul>​
```

**Css**

```
  ul.navi{
    margin:10px 0 0 10px;
    width:300px;
}

ul.navi li{
    background:#1f1f1f;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
ul.navi li:after{
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #2a2a2a;
    border-top:solid 1px #171717;
}
ul.navi li:last-child:after{
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    border:0;
}

ul.navi li a{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#989898;
    line-height:45px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-left:20px;
}
ul.navi li a:hover{
    color:#fff;
}​
```

and now Live demo [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/8abUy/4/) 
http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/8abUy/4/

Comment: Thats nice but the bottom border shouldnt stretch all the way.

Comment: Here is the image i want to use.. Its not that i cant make the UL Li menu.. I am having problems because i dont know how to make the line and the indend.

Comment: so you mean the border bottom should touch the complete UL from left & right & you dont need margins on border bottom of left & right side ?

Comment: the bottom border should NOT touch the end of the li. in my design its in the middle.